# Django 2 Allauth email confirmation redirects to empty page

Tags: django, django-views, django-allauth

I'm trying to set up `allauth` and it's been challenging to say the least.

My registration page works (although the `username` field refuses to appear on the form) and on submission, redirects a user to an empty page with a banner saying `Check your email to confirm account`

The email says

```
To confirm this is correct, go to http://localhost:8000/users/verify-email/Ng:1h2xx7:z9x0t0wmvAhicak5twI_QtVWNYo
```

When I click on the link, the page is empty (although still styled by my `base.html`, there is no content.)

I'm assuming it should be directing to the login page and showing a banner `Account confirmed, you may now log in.`

Can someone please indicate to me why this is happening?

Is there a views.py class for the page after email confirmation I should know about?

urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from users import views as user_views
from allauth.account.views import confirm_email

urlpatterns = [
    path('register', user_views.MySignupView.as_view(template_name='users/register.html'), name='register'),
    path('login', user_views.MyLoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('verify-email/<str:key>',
    confirm_email,
    name='account_confirm_email'),
```

views.py

```
from allauth.account.views import SignupView, LoginView

class MySignupView(SignupView):
    template_name = 'users/register.html'

class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'users/login.html'
```

forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
```

settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'users.forms.UserRegisterForm'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS=7
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 5
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_TIMEOUT = 86400 # 1 day in seconds
```

Comment: Check if you have `templates/account/email_confirm.html` somewhere in your project folder

Comment: No I didn't have that folder, I've now added it and it shows a totally blank page. I've copied my code from my `login` page for the time being but is that the answer? Just style that page to say thanks for confirming your email, then have a link to direct them to the login page? And how can I verify the email is actually being confirmed?

Comment: This template should be called: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/account/email_confirm.html You can try to copy that over and see if that helps. Either way something seems to be called because you're not getting a template not found error

Comment: Yeah I just can't figure out what's being called...strangely when I paste that template into the `email_confirm.html` the empty page reappears

Comment: Check the html generated, can maybe give you a clue to what's going on. Also I recommend you install https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar

Comment: I've checked the html and there are no clues there, I'll install the debug toolbar. It just seems like the allauth templates aren't getting called, and even when I call them manually, like above, they don't display anything. The only time the templates have rendered appropriately is when I did this `class MySignupView(SignupView):
    template_name = 'users/register.html'` before that they showed the same empty pages..

Comment: Okay, well I just edited that github template from `{% block content %}` to `{% block body %}` and that did the trick. But it's not possible to go through every template and do that?

Comment: well `{% block content %}` is the preferred way to call your block. not sure why you're using `body`. I'd change all templates to use `content` if I were you

Comment: Most packages assume there's a `{% block content %}` in your base template, so if you want to re-use them, I'd change your base template to use `{% block content %}` instead of `body`. Also you should not change the templates inside allauth if you need to change/override them. Rather, you should create your own _account/email_confirm.html_ template inside an `account` directory in your app's template directory. This will automatically supersede the _account/email_confirm.html_ template of allauth.

Comment: Yes not sure why quite a few sites I was using as a reference were using `{% block body %}`...I'll change mine now. That way I can delete the `account` directory as I don't need to override it.

Comment: Will I need to keep the directory as the `allauth` files have `{% extends "account/base.html" %}` but I want it to be `{% extends "base.html" %}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using `{% block body %}` instead of `{% block content %}` so that's why the page was styled but empty.